# Play Iteratee for this use case

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.1

I am learning Iteratee and related APIs for one of my requirements to stream live tweets. Using Play 2.1 and Scala 2.10. Is following the best way to use Iteratee which also produces result of saving tweet to MongoDB?

```
val wsStream = new Enumerator[Array[Byte]] {
  def apply[A](iteratee: Iteratee[Array[Byte], A]) = {
    WS.url("https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json?track=" + term)
      .sign(OAuthCalculator(Twitter.KEY, tokens))
      .get(_ => iteratee)
  }
}

wsStream.apply(Iteratee.foreach(bytes => saveTweetToMongo(bytes)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Note you you can apply multiple iteratees to the same enumerator.  In order words you can create a `streamingTweetIteratee` and a `saveTweetToMongoIteratee` and apply both to the enumerator which provides tweets.

I often create a simple `loggingIteratee` which just funnels everything to STDOUT when I'm prototyping in the REPL.  I apply both it and the iteratee I'm writing to the same enumerator.

I'm assuming you want to using WebSockets in order to stream tweets to a client?  If you look at the chat demo that comes with Play! you'll get an idea of how to go about that.